# Calling fragment from ViewPager fragment

Tags: android

I am getting error while calling Fragment from tab fragment.
I have MainActivity which use TabFragment which use ViewPager.
In ViewPager I have 4 tabs. I am calling another fragment from 1st tab fragment.

MainActivity

```
 TabFragment tabFrag = new TabFragment();

    mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new TabFragment()).commit();
```

Now from TabFragment which extends Fragment I am calling 4 fragment on different tabs.

```
**  @Override
public Fragment getItem(int position){
    Fragment fragment=null;
    switch (position){
        case 0 : {
                  fragment= new PostFragment();
                  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                  bundle.putString("fragmentName","0");
                  fragment.setArguments(bundle);return fragment;
                 }

        case 1 : {fragment= new EventFragment();
                  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                  bundle.putString("fragmentName","1");
                  fragment.setArguments(bundle);return fragment;}
        case 2 : {fragment= new ServiceFragment();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("fragmentName","2");
                    fragment.setArguments(bundle);return fragment;
                 }
        case 3 : {fragment= new AccountFragment();
                  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                  bundle.putString("fragmentName","3");
                  fragment.setArguments(bundle);return fragment;
        }
    }
    return fragment;
}
```

Now In PostFragment I am calling another fragment PostQuestionFragment on button click.

```
   public void onClick(View view) {
    int id = view.getId();
    switch (id){
        case R.id.post:


            animateFAB();
            break;
        case R.id.postQue:
        {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            PostQuestionFragment postQuestionFragment = new PostQuestionFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, postQuestionFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            break;
        }


        case R.id.fab2:


            break;
    }
}
```

I am getting error on fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, postQuestionFragment); Below is the log information.

```
4836/com.lab.bankersbank E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.lab.bankersbank, PID: 14836
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c007f (com.lab.bankersbank:id/containerView) for fragment PostQuestionFragment{85a5fe #2 id=0x7f0c007f}
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1059)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Updated :

MainActivity.java

```
 private static final String VIEW_KEY1 ="key1" ;
private static final String VIEW_KEY2 ="key2" ;
FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton notifBtn = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.post);
    FloatingActionButton postBtn = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.post);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    TabFragment tabFrag = new TabFragment();
    mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new TabFragment()).commit();

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();


    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help.

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: R.id.containerView exists in your main_activity layout? Android is looking for that view to insert the Fragment but is not finding.. So, you did not call setContentView() before, or R.id.containerView is not present in the mainActivity or you must clear/rebuild your project to re-generate R.java file

Comment: Yes mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new TabFragment()).commit();

Comment: Share your MainActivity.java and main_activity.xml layout

Comment: code added in question.